# How to use dis.download in flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to download pdf file using dio flutter package, but I don't
know how it'll done in flutter web.

dio.download :

```
dio.download(url,path) // syntax [how do I set path for flutter web?]
response = await dio.download('https://www.google.com/', './xx.html');
```